# Multiple SlideToggle jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `slideToggle` that is moving the content down to make it visible. However, at the moment, I have multiple of these on one page. So when one is clicked, they all move the content down and make it visible. What I would like to do is when one is clicked ONLY just that one `.tst` element is toggled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.tst').hide();
    $("div.slide").addClass('up_arrow')
     $("div.slide").click(function(){
         $("div.slide").toggleClass('up_arrow').toggleClass('down_arrow');
         $(".tst").slideToggle( 'slow', function(){
         });
      });
</script>
```

Is there a way to make this just slide down the one you click as opposed to all the `.tst` divs?

EDIT: HTML markup as requested:

```
<div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="tst">
        <div class="courseinfo">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><b>»</b>&nbsp;<a href="#">info</a></li>
                        <li>info</li>
                        <li><span class="rowUCAS">info</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#">External link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should include your HTML as well.

Comment: You'll want to target each of them with id's, not by class.

Comment: You should either assign/use "id" for each .tst element associated with its toggle control, or try to use .closest() selector, depends on your HTML. Rgds, AB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the selector inside the function, use `$(this)` to target the element which was clicked. In yor case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.tst').hide();
    $("div.slide").addClass('up_arrow')
     $("div.slide").click(function(){
         $(this).toggleClass('up_arrow').toggleClass('down_arrow');
         $(".tst").slideToggle('slow')
      });
</script>
```

The selector `$(this)` targets the element that is triggering the event.

Following the HTML markup given:

```
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="tst">
    ...
</div>
```

the following selector would work:

```
$("div.slide").click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('up_arrow').toggleClass('down_arrow');
     $(this).next().slideToggle('slow')
});
```

You may be interested in nesting the `.tst` in the `div.slide` like so:

```
<div class="slide">
    <div class="tst">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

In which case, the following selector would work

```
$("div.slide").click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('up_arrow').toggleClass('down_arrow');
     $(this).children('.tst').slideToggle('slow')
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @Sikian - thank you for getting back to me, and with a great answer. It worked, but only for the toggleClass, what I need is to target the .tst as the above code will only toggle that individual swap of class. How would I only slideToggle that individual .tst ?
- 
Hope that makes sense?

Comment: I'm afraid I'll need the html code to be able to help you with that, as I don't know what relationship is there between .tst and the div.slide.

Comment: Hi @Sikian - I have just updated my question with HTML mark up that would hopefully help with anything? Just trying to get this nailed as it's the last bit to be fixed! So any help I would appreciate...

Comment: Updated it :) If anything goes awry, just tell me.

Comment: Great @Sikian! Spot on, and it worked like a charge, I now also understand how the (this) works so this gives me a bit of an understanding into targeting things individually as the relying on divs. Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: Glad it helped both in you problem and gave you some knowledge on its use >)
Remember to use jQuery docs when something is unclear.